# Getting data from Steam Store API using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, rest, json.net, steam, steam-web-api

I am trying to get the data from the Steam Store API. The goal is to pass it an AppID and then get the data for that game using the API and storing it in a **Game** object. I am fetching the data up until serialization. The below is the code I an using:

```
namespace GData
{

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Game _9050 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Game
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int steam_appid { get; set; }
        public int required_age { get; set; }
        public bool is_free { get; set; }
        public string detailed_description { get; set; }
        public string about_the_game { get; set; }
        public string short_description { get; set; }
        public string supported_languages { get; set; }
        public string header_image { get; set; }
        public string website { get; set; }
        public Pc_Requirements pc_requirements { get; set; }
        public object[] mac_requirements { get; set; }
        public object[] linux_requirements { get; set; }
        public string[] developers { get; set; }
        public string[] publishers { get; set; }
        public Price_Overview price_overview { get; set; }
        public int[] packages { get; set; }
        public Package_Groups[] package_groups { get; set; }
        public Platforms platforms { get; set; }
        public Metacritic metacritic { get; set; }
        public Category[] categories { get; set; }
        public Genre[] genres { get; set; }
        public Screenshot[] screenshots { get; set; }
        public Recommendations recommendations { get; set; }
        public Release_Date release_date { get; set; }
        public Support_Info support_info { get; set; }
        public string background { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pc_Requirements
    {
        public string minimum { get; set; }
    }

    public class Price_Overview
    {
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public int initial { get; set; }
        public int final { get; set; }
        public int discount_percent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Platforms
    {
        public bool windows { get; set; }
        public bool mac { get; set; }
        public bool linux { get; set; }
    }

    public class Metacritic
    {
        public int score { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Recommendations
    {
        public int total { get; set; }
    }

    public class Release_Date
    {
        public bool coming_soon { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
    }

    public class Support_Info
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Package_Groups
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string selection_text { get; set; }
        public string save_text { get; set; }
        public int display_type { get; set; }
        public string is_recurring_subscription { get; set; }
        public Sub[] subs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sub
    {
        public int packageid { get; set; }
        public string percent_savings_text { get; set; }
        public int percent_savings { get; set; }
        public string option_text { get; set; }
        public string option_description { get; set; }
        public string can_get_free_license { get; set; }
        public bool is_free_license { get; set; }
        public int price_in_cents_with_discount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Genre
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Screenshot
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string path_thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string path_full { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Fetching JSON:

```
 public class GameData
    {
        public Game GetGameData(int GameId)
        {
            var url = "https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=" + GameId.ToString();
            //Game GameData = _download_serialized_json_data<Game>(url);
            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(url));

            WebReq.Method = "GET";

            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);

            string jsonString;
            using (Stream stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream())  
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Game GameData = new Game();

            GameData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(jsonString);

            return GameData;
        }

    }
```

The code is returning success: false.

The issue seems to be in the deserialization as the `jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();` jsonString variable is getting full with the data.

Is there something wrong in the `Game` class?

I am using C# and the Newtonsoft JSON library.

Sample JSON retrieved in **jsonString** (https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=570):

```
 {
   "570":{
      "success":true,
      "data":{
         "type":"game",
         "name":"Dota 2",
         "steam_appid":570,
         "required_age":0,
         "is_free":true,
         "dlc":[
            859040
         ],
         "detailed_description":"<strong>The most-played game on Steam.<\/strong><br>Every day, millions of players worldwide enter battle as one of over a hundred Dota heroes. And no matter if it's their 10th hour of play or 1,000th, there's always something new to discover. With regular updates that ensure a constant evolution of gameplay, features, and heroes, Dota 2 has truly taken on a life of its own.<br><br><strong>One Battlefield. Infinite Possibilities.<\/strong><br>When it comes to diversity of heroes, abilities, and powerful items, Dota boasts an endless array\u2014no two games are the same. Any hero can fill multiple roles, and there's an abundance of items to help meet the needs of each game. Dota doesn't provide limitations on how to play, it empowers you to express your own style.<br><br><strong>All heroes are free.<\/strong><br>Competitive balance is Dota's crown jewel, and to ensure everyone is playing on an even field, the core content of the game\u2014like the vast pool of heroes\u2014is available to all players. Fans can collect cosmetics for heroes and fun add-ons for the world they inhabit, but everything you need to play is already included before you join your first match.<br><br><strong>Bring your friends and party up.<\/strong><br>Dota is deep, and constantly evolving, but it's never too late to join. <br>Learn the ropes playing co-op vs. bots. Sharpen your skills in the hero demo mode. Jump into the behavior- and skill-based matchmaking system that ensures you'll <br>be matched with the right players each game.",
         "about_the_game":"<strong>The most-played game on Steam.<\/strong><br>Every day, millions of players worldwide enter battle as one of over a hundred Dota heroes. And no matter if it's their 10th hour of play or 1,000th, there's always something new to discover. With regular updates that ensure a constant evolution of gameplay, features, and heroes, Dota 2 has truly taken on a life of its own.<br><br><strong>One Battlefield. Infinite Possibilities.<\/strong><br>When it comes to diversity of heroes, abilities, and powerful items, Dota boasts an endless array\u2014no two games are the same. Any hero can fill multiple roles, and there's an abundance of items to help meet the needs of each game. Dota doesn't provide limitations on how to play, it empowers you to express your own style.<br><br><strong>All heroes are free.<\/strong><br>Competitive balance is Dota's crown jewel, and to ensure everyone is playing on an even field, the core content of the game\u2014like the vast pool of heroes\u2014is available to all players. Fans can collect cosmetics for heroes and fun add-ons for the world they inhabit, but everything you need to play is already included before you join your first match.<br><br><strong>Bring your friends and party up.<\/strong><br>Dota is deep, and constantly evolving, but it's never too late to join. <br>Learn the ropes playing co-op vs. bots. Sharpen your skills in the hero demo mode. Jump into the behavior- and skill-based matchmaking system that ensures you'll <br>be matched with the right players each game.",
         "short_description":"Every day, millions of players worldwide enter battle as one of over a hundred Dota heroes. And no matter if it's their 10th hour of play or 1,000th, there's always something new to discover. With regular updates that ensure a constant evolution of gameplay, features, and heroes, Dota 2 has truly taken on a life of its own.",
         "supported_languages":"Bulgarian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, English<strong>*<\/strong>, Finnish, French, German, Greek, Hungarian, Italian, Japanese, Korean<strong>*<\/strong>, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Portuguese-Brazil, Romanian, Russian, Simplified Chinese<strong>*<\/strong>, Spanish, Swedish, Thai, Traditional Chinese, Turkish, Ukrainian<br><strong>*<\/strong>languages with full audio support",
         "reviews":"\u201cA modern multiplayer masterpiece.\u201d<br>9.5\/10 \u2013 <a href=\"https:\/\/www.destructoid.com\/review-dota-2-258506.phtml\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noreferrer\"  >Destructoid<\/a><br><br>\u201cOnce you start to learn its secrets, there\u2019s a wild and exciting variety of play here that\u2019s unmatched, even by its peers.\u201d<br>9.4\/10 \u2013 <a href=\"http:\/\/www.ign.com\/articles\/2013\/07\/24\/dota-2-review\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noreferrer\"  >IGN<\/a><br><br>\u201cDota 2 is possibly the only competitive free-to-play game that is totally uncompromised by its business model.\u201d<br>90\/100 \u2013 <a href=\"http:\/\/www.pcgamer.com\/dota-2-review-2\/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noreferrer\"  >PC Gamer<\/a><br>",
         "header_image":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/header.jpg?t=1525818062",
         "website":"http:\/\/www.dota2.com\/",
         "pc_requirements":{
            "minimum":"<strong>Minimum:<\/strong><br><ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li><strong>OS:<\/strong> Windows 7 or newer<br><\/li><li><strong>Processor:<\/strong> Dual core from Intel or AMD at 2.8 GHz<br><\/li><li><strong>Memory:<\/strong> 4 GB RAM<br><\/li><li><strong>Graphics:<\/strong> nVidia GeForce 8600\/9600GT, ATI\/AMD Radeon HD2600\/3600<br><\/li><li><strong>DirectX:<\/strong> Version 9.0c<br><\/li><li><strong>Network:<\/strong> Broadband Internet connection<br><\/li><li><strong>Storage:<\/strong> 15 GB available space<br><\/li><li><strong>Sound Card:<\/strong> DirectX Compatible<\/li><\/ul>"
         },
         "mac_requirements":{
            "minimum":"<strong>Minimum:<\/strong><br><ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li><strong>OS:<\/strong> OS X Mavericks 10.9 or newer<br><\/li><li><strong>Processor:<\/strong> Dual core from Intel<br><\/li><li><strong>Memory:<\/strong> 4 GB RAM<br><\/li><li><strong>Graphics:<\/strong> nVidia 320M or higher, or Radeon HD 2400 or higher, or Intel HD 3000 or higher<br><\/li><li><strong>Network:<\/strong> Broadband Internet connection<br><\/li><li><strong>Storage:<\/strong> 15 GB available space<\/li><\/ul>"
         },
         "linux_requirements":{
            "minimum":"<strong>Minimum:<\/strong><br><ul class=\"bb_ul\"><li><strong>OS:<\/strong> Ubuntu 12.04 or newer<br><\/li><li><strong>Processor:<\/strong> Dual core from Intel or AMD at 2.8 GHz<br><\/li><li><strong>Memory:<\/strong> 4 GB RAM<br><\/li><li><strong>Graphics:<\/strong> nVidia Geforce 8600\/9600GT (Driver v331), AMD HD 2xxx-4xxx (Driver mesa 10.5.9), AMD HD 5xxx+ (Driver mesa 10.5.9 or Catalyst 15.7), Intel HD 3000 (Driver mesa 10.6)<br><\/li><li><strong>Network:<\/strong> Broadband Internet connection<br><\/li><li><strong>Storage:<\/strong> 15 GB available space<br><\/li><li><strong>Sound Card:<\/strong> OpenAL Compatible Sound Card<\/li><\/ul>"
         },
         "developers":[
            "Valve"
         ],
         "publishers":[
            "Valve"
         ],
         "packages":[
            197846
         ],
         "package_groups":[
            {
               "name":"default",
               "title":"Buy Dota 2",
               "description":"",
               "selection_text":"Select a purchase option",
               "save_text":"",
               "display_type":0,
               "is_recurring_subscription":"false",
               "subs":[
                  {
                     "packageid":197846,
                     "percent_savings_text":"",
                     "percent_savings":0,
                     "option_text":"Dota 2 - Commercial License - Free",
                     "option_description":"",
                     "can_get_free_license":"0",
                     "is_free_license":true,
                     "price_in_cents_with_discount":0
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "platforms":{
            "windows":true,
            "mac":true,
            "linux":true
         },
         "metacritic":{
            "score":90,
            "url":"http:\/\/www.metacritic.com\/game\/pc\/dota-2?ftag=MCD-06-10aaa1f"
         },
         "categories":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "description":"Multi-player"
            },
            {
               "id":9,
               "description":"Co-op"
            },
            {
               "id":29,
               "description":"Steam Trading Cards"
            },
            {
               "id":30,
               "description":"Steam Workshop"
            },
            {
               "id":40,
               "description":"SteamVR Collectibles"
            },
            {
               "id":35,
               "description":"In-App Purchases"
            },
            {
               "id":8,
               "description":"Valve Anti-Cheat enabled"
            }
         ],
         "genres":[
            {
               "id":"1",
               "description":"Action"
            },
            {
               "id":"37",
               "description":"Free to Play"
            },
            {
               "id":"2",
               "description":"Strategy"
            }
         ],
         "screenshots":[
            {
               "id":0,
               "path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_86d675fdc73ba10462abb8f5ece7791c5047072c.600x338.jpg?t=1525818062",
               "path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_86d675fdc73ba10462abb8f5ece7791c5047072c.1920x1080.jpg?t=1525818062"
            },
            {
               "id":1,
               "path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_ad8eee787704745ccdecdfde3a5cd2733704898d.600x338.jpg?t=1525818062",
               "path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_ad8eee787704745ccdecdfde3a5cd2733704898d.1920x1080.jpg?t=1525818062"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_7ab506679d42bfc0c0e40639887176494e0466d9.600x338.jpg?t=1525818062",
               "path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_7ab506679d42bfc0c0e40639887176494e0466d9.1920x1080.jpg?t=1525818062"
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_c9118375a2400278590f29a3537769c986ef6e39.600x338.jpg?t=1525818062",
               "path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_c9118375a2400278590f29a3537769c986ef6e39.1920x1080.jpg?t=1525818062"
            },
            {
               "id":4,
               "path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_f9ebafedaf2d5cfb80ef1f74baa18eb08cad6494.600x338.jpg?t=1525818062",
               "path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_f9ebafedaf2d5cfb80ef1f74baa18eb08cad6494.1920x1080.jpg?t=1525818062"
            },
            {
               "id":5,
               "path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_27b6345f22243bd6b885cc64c5cda74e4bd9c3e8.600x338.jpg?t=1525818062",
               "path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_27b6345f22243bd6b885cc64c5cda74e4bd9c3e8.1920x1080.jpg?t=1525818062"
            },
            {
               "id":6,
               "path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_b33a65678dc71cc98df4890e22a89601ee56a918.600x338.jpg?t=1525818062",
               "path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_b33a65678dc71cc98df4890e22a89601ee56a918.1920x1080.jpg?t=1525818062"
            },
            {
               "id":7,
               "path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_d0f973ce376ca5b6c08e081cb035e86ced105fa9.600x338.jpg?t=1525818062",
               "path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_d0f973ce376ca5b6c08e081cb035e86ced105fa9.1920x1080.jpg?t=1525818062"
            },
            {
               "id":8,
               "path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_1f3b5f5ccf8b159294914c3fe028128a787304b6.600x338.jpg?t=1525818062",
               "path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_1f3b5f5ccf8b159294914c3fe028128a787304b6.1920x1080.jpg?t=1525818062"
            },
            {
               "id":9,
               "path_thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_e0a92f15a6631a8186df79182d0fe28b5e37d8cb.600x338.jpg?t=1525818062",
               "path_full":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/ss_e0a92f15a6631a8186df79182d0fe28b5e37d8cb.1920x1080.jpg?t=1525818062"
            }
         ],
         "movies":[
            {
               "id":256692021,
               "name":"Dota 2 - Join the Battle",
               "thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256692021\/movie.293x165.jpg?t=1501892790",
               "webm":{
                  "480":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256692021\/movie480.webm?t=1501892790",
                  "max":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256692021\/movie_max.webm?t=1501892790"
               },
               "highlight":true
            },
            {
               "id":256692017,
               "name":"Dota 2 - Sizzle Reel",
               "thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256692017\/movie.293x165.jpg?t=1501892798",
               "webm":{
                  "480":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256692017\/movie480.webm?t=1501892798",
                  "max":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/256692017\/movie_max.webm?t=1501892798"
               },
               "highlight":true
            },
            {
               "id":2028243,
               "name":"Dota 2 - The Greeviling",
               "thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/2028243\/movie.293x165.jpg?t=1447357208",
               "webm":{
                  "480":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/2028243\/movie480.webm?t=1447357208",
                  "max":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/2028243\/movie_max.webm?t=1447357208"
               },
               "highlight":false
            },
            {
               "id":81026,
               "name":"Dota 2 Gamescom Trailer",
               "thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/81026\/movie.293x165.jpg?t=1501892804",
               "webm":{
                  "480":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/81026\/movie480.webm?t=1501892804",
                  "max":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/81026\/movie_max.webm?t=1501892804"
               },
               "highlight":false
            },
            {
               "id":2040250,
               "name":"Dota 2 Reborn - Custom Games Are Here",
               "thumbnail":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/2040250\/movie.293x165.jpg?t=1447376742",
               "webm":{
                  "480":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/2040250\/movie480.webm?t=1447376742",
                  "max":"http:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/2040250\/movie_max.webm?t=1447376742"
               },
               "highlight":false
            }
         ],
         "recommendations":{
            "total":911325
         },
         "release_date":{
            "coming_soon":false,
            "date":"9 Jul, 2013"
         },
         "support_info":{
            "url":"http:\/\/dev.dota2.com\/",
            "email":""
         },
         "background":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steam\/apps\/570\/page_bg_generated_v6b.jpg?t=1525818062"
      }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE: if I return Data datatype all value are null**

```
    public Data GetGameData(int GameId)
    {
    var url = "https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=" + GameId.ToString();
    //Game GameData = _download_serialized_json_data<Game>(url);
    HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(url));

    WebReq.Method = "GET";

    HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

    Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);

    string jsonString;
    using (Stream stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(jsonString);

    Data gameData = dict[GameId.ToString()];

    return gameData;
}
```

**If I return Game datatype I get the same error:**

```
 public Game GetGameData(int GameId)
            {
            var url = "https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=" + GameId.ToString();
            //Game GameData = _download_serialized_json_data<Game>(url);
            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(url));

            WebReq.Method = "GET";

            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);

            string jsonString;
            using (Stream stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Game>>(jsonString);

            Game gameData = dict[GameId.ToString()];

            return gameData;
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the sample json which you are getting back from the API?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Done. Updated question with sample json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are attempting to deserialize into a `Game` class containing `success` and `data` properties.  However, in sample JSON, these properties are not at the root level.  Instead, they are one level further down, inside a property called `570`, which I am guessing is the game ID:

```
{
  "570": {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Since the class you are deserializing into doesn't match up with the JSON, you are getting default values (i.e. `success` is false and `data` is null).

To fix this, you will need something to wrap your `Game` class.  And since the game ID will probably change depending on the request, you can't use a regular class like `Rootobject`.  Instead you will need to deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, Game>` like this:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Game>>(jsonString);
```

You can then retrieve the `Game` object from that:

```
Game gameData = dict[GameId.ToString()];
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ieT839

Note: In your classes, you can omit members that you don't really need.  In playing around with different game ID's I discovered that the `pc_requirements`, `mac_requirements` and `linux_requirements` elements in the JSON can sometimes be an object and sometimes an array of objects.  If you have your classes declared to expect one thing and the JSON returns the other, then you will get an error when deserializing.  You can solve this problem using a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) like the `SingleOrArrayConverter<T>` from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/10263).  But if you don't really need those items, you can sidestep the issue just by commenting them out in your `Data` class.

Comment: All the values returned are null (updated question with updated code).

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure what's going wrong for you.  I updated my answer with a link to a working demo.  Hopefully that will help.  Also added some info about handling certain items that might be a single object or an array, which could be tripping you up.  I'm not sure.  Your updated question mentions an error, but you never said what the error was.

Comment: Worked like a charm.. thanks! I think the issue was `public class Webm
{
    [JsonProperty("480")]
    public string _480 { get; set; }
    public string max { get; set; }
}`